# Solr Create collection error

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I'm using HDP 2.5 and latest solr version 7.1.0. When i try to create collection via solr i got below error, I think the problem is there in zookeeper. Please find my log

```
$ ./solr create -c test_solr./solr: line 2017: /opt/solr-7.1.0/solr-7.1.0/bin/solr-8983.pid: Permission denied
Warning: Available entropy is low. As a result, use of the UUIDField, SSL, or any other features that require
RNG might not work properly. To check for the amount of available entropy, use 'cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail'.
Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [\]  
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=24630). Happy searching!

$ ./solr create -c test_solr
WARNING: Using _default configset. Data driven schema functionality is enabled by default, which is
         NOT RECOMMENDED for production use.
         To turn it off:
            curl http://localhost:8886/solr/test_solr/config -d '{"set-user-property": {"update.autoCreateFields":"false"}}'

ERROR: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /clusterstate.json
```

I can able to get collection in solr admin ui. But i cannot able to create collection. Please give me some solution!!.

Answer (score 0):

The version you're using for HDP seems to try to integrate directly with Zookeeper and Solr, for example through the SolrJ client.

The version used of SolrJ - or the library created in HDP - is too old, and hasn't been ported to the more modern version of Solr where each collection has its own state.json - and clusterstate.json has been removed.

You might have more luck with an older Solr version (4.10.2), but this version lacks much of what modern Solr supports.

Comment: Thanks gave some suggestion.

Comment: I also just saw that you have different port numbers in the two commands, 8983 in one and 8886 in the other .. make sure you're using the correct one.

Comment: Thanks i can able to create collection now. but older version only. when i hit in new solr 7.1.0 i got error Error CREATEing SolrCore 'Sample_test_shard1_replica_n1': Couldn't persist core properties

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue for the Solr directory.